# Apache Beam/Google dataflow Python streaming autoscaling

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Following this link to the Apache Beam website https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-streaming/, it states the following (at the bottom of the page):

> DataflowRunner does not currently support the following Cloud Dataflow
>   specific features with Python streaming execution.
>
> - Streaming autoscaling

Is there some sort of roadmap that specifies when this will be supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache BEAM uses Jira for issue tracking.

For example, you can filter the issues using these criteria:

Containing Text:

- Cloud Dataflow

By Issue type:

- New Feature
- Improvement
- Wish

By Status:

- Open
- In Progress
- Reopened

As of now, this query brings 56 results: [Apache BEAM Jira Issues](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-1251?jql=project%20%3D%20BEAM%20AND%20issuetype%20in%20(Improvement%2C%20%22New%20Feature%22%2C%20Wish)%20AND%20status%20in%20(Open%2C%20%22In%20Progress%22%2C%20Reopened)%20AND%20resolution%20%3D%20Unresolved%20AND%20text%20~%20%22Cloud%20Dataflow%22%20ORDER%20BY%20priority%20DESC%2C%20updated%20DESC)